# How to use,get values fromm check box in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I am new to ruby on rails...I am not getting how to work with the check box, how to get the values from the check box and also the requirement is, if I select the main check box means it should mark all the check box present in that view. Please help...Is it possible to achive this one without using java script...

Comment: You need to add some more to this, perhaps a sample of code you've already tried

Comment: For getting all checkbox checked on main check box you need to do it using javascript or jquery can follow below  link http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/01/how-to-select-all-deselect-checkboxes-jquery

Comment: Its easy if you read the official documentation on forms, checkboxes & other components http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. here we expect you to do some research on the topic, read some tutorials (the above comments have given some good starting places), then to have a go at it yourself before asking for help. if you're still stuck, come back here and copy in the code you've tried (so we know what you're trying to do), and tell us about the research you've done - so we can see that you've made some kind of effort to solve the problem. A verbal description is very hard to go-on to help you solve your problem.